# Keep ViewModel list populated from HTTPGet to HTTPPost ActionResult

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, viewmodel, html.hiddenfor

In an MVC5 internet application, how can I keep the contents of a `ViewModel List`, between the `HTTPGet` request and the `HTTPPost` request.

I have done some searching, but am not sure exactly what term to search for.

Here is my situation:

I have a `ViewModel`, that has the following list populated in the `HTTPGet ActionResult`:

```
public List<string> azureBlobFullFileNames { get; set; }
```

In the `HTTPPost ActionResult`, the list is null.

How can I still have the list populated with values in the `HTTPPost ActionResult`?

I have added the following code after the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` View line of code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.azureBlobFullFileNames)
```

However, the list is still null in the `HTTPPost ActionResult`.

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to generate a control for each element of a collection in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a control for element in the collection using a `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.azureBlobFullFileNames.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.azureBlobFullFileNames[i])
}
```